Why is this seemingly redundant Python import statement necessary?
This snippet of Python 3.12 code:
import paho
import paho.mqtt.client  # line 2

client = paho.mqtt.client.Client(paho.mqtt.enums.CallbackAPIVersion(2))

fails when line #2 is commented out. paho module is imported by the first line. I'm using the full name paho.mqtt.client.Client in the last line. Why is the seemingly redundant import paho.mqtt.client necessary?
Is there a way to import paho.mqtt module, so it can be used to shorten both paho.mqtt.client.Client and paho.mqtt.enums.CallbackAPIVersion names?

No, you can't do anything - that is the library's design by the author. paho.__init__ runs no code (so import paho doesn't do anything), and paho.mqtt.__init__ also doesn't import anything from paho. If you want import paho.mqtt to allow you to access .client and .enums, paho.mqtt.__init__ needs to directly or indirectly run code which triggers an import from paho.mqtt.client and paho.mqtt.enums.

@dROOOze Thanks. It was quite surprising to me.

In general, import foo does not mean that a submodule foo.bar will be imported, although, a library author can make that happen. It is typical for many libraries to conveniently flatten a namespace for whatever is being exposed, though. An example is the pandas library, which exposes pandas.Dataframe in the base module pandas, but it is actually defined in a submodule and explicitly put into the pandas namespace (from pandas.core.frame)

https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#python-packages

You can technically import the package as well
But this is of little avail. Though this is, strictly speaking, a syntactically correct Python statement, it doesn’t do much of anything useful. In particular, it does not place any of the modules in pkg into the local namespace:

Importing the paho package does not import the mqtt subpackage, or the client module.
Line 1, the import paho is the unnecessary import.
